# Image of symmetric group is a reflection group

Tags: invariant-theory

Let $V$ be $n$-dimensional complex vector space with basis $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ and let $\phi\colon S_n \to GL(V)$ be homomorphism of groups such that $\phi(\sigma)e_j = e_\sigma(j), j = 1,...,n$.

Prove that $G = \operatorname{Im} \phi$ is reflection group and find her exponents.

($S_n$ is symmetric group of order $n$ and $\sigma$ is pseudoreflection).

Comment: Can you tell which elements of $S_n$ are mapped to reflections, at least?

Comment: $\sigma$ is not a pseudoreflection (that does not even make sense, really...): it is a permutation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $S_n$ is generated by permutations that interchange two numbers while leaving the other $n-2$ numbers fixed. Show that permutations of this sort are sent by $\phi$ to reflections.

Comment: Ok, thank you. S_n is reflection group, right?

Comment: To be precise, $S_n$ is isomorphic, via $\phi$, to a reflection group.  Strictly speaking, a reflection group has to be a group of linear transformations of a vector space, and $S_n$, being a group of permutations of a finite set, isn't such a group, so $S_n$ is not literally a reflection group.